# ROC of z transform of u(-n+1)

Tags: z-transform

I am having confusion regarding ROC of z transform of u(-n+1)

z transform of u(-n+1) is given by

$$X(z)=Z[u(-n+1)] = 
\sum_{n=-\infty}^1 z^{-n} =\sum_{n=-1}^\infty z^n = z^{-1} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n  $$

ROC given: 0<|z|<1

While I understand that |z| should be less than 1 so that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n  $$ converge, I don't understand why |z| should be greater than 0. Please clarify this doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since

\$|z| = 0 ~~\Leftrightarrow~~ z = 0 \$

for z = 0 you cannot compute the term outside the sum symbol, i.e. \$z^{-1}\$, which is part of your transform. In other words, for \$z = 0\$ the transform does not exist.

Maybe you were put off-tracks because \$|z|\ge 0\$ by definition, but now you have to exclude \$ |z| = 0 \$ from the interval of valid values of \$|z|\$.

Comment: What about negative values of z? Why wont it converge for negative values of z

Comment: Understood. The negative values of z are included in 0<|z|<1. Isint it?

Comment: @user3237657 z is a complex number, it has no "negative values". The ROC is the circle, in the complex plane, centered at the origin with radius 1 (except the origin itself and the border of the circle).